# How to combine two mySQL INSERT queries into one?

Tags: php, mysql

is there any way to combine two INSERT queries into one query ?

Thank you

```
    mysql_query("INSERT into `new_table` (`hash`,`first_visit`, `country`, `browser`) values ('$hash',CURDATE(), '$details->geoplugin_countryCode','$_SERVER[HTTP_USER_AGENT]')");
    mysql_query("INSERT into `behaviour` (`hash`,`page`,`url`,`entry`, `ref`) values ('$hash','$page','$url','$entry', '$ref')");
```

Comment: Why would you do this?

Comment: No, you can't..

Comment: its two table not one

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation "mysql_query() sends a unique query (multiple queries are not supported) to the currently active database on the server that's associated with the specified link_identifier."  So, no you can't combine those inserts.

But you could use `multi_query` and do something like this:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";
$hash  = "foo" ; 
$page = "bar" ;
$url =  "baz" ;
$entry = "something" 
$ref  = "silly" ; 


// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO newtable (hash, first_visit, country, browser)
VALUES ('$hash',CURDATE(), '$details>geoplugin_countryCode','$_SERVER[HTTP_USER_AGENT]');";
$sql .= "INSERT INTO behaviour (hash, page, url, entry, ref)
VALUES ( $hash, $page, $url, $entry, $ref);";

if ($conn->multi_query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New records created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score -3):

```
mysql_query("
    INSERT into `new_table` (`hash`,`first_visit`, `country`, `browser`) values ('$hash',CURDATE(), '$details->geoplugin_countryCode','$_SERVER[HTTP_USER_AGENT]');
    INSERT into `behaviour` (`hash`,`page`,`url`,`entry`, `ref`) values ('$hash','$page','$url','$entry', '$ref')
");
```

Just add ; after statement

Edit: Still 2 DB queries, but send in 1 request